# Error "You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP"

Tags: django, http, ssl, https

[image: SSL connection]

When I try to write the server link like http:// .... it redirects to https:// and in the terminal :

```
message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x16\x03\x01\x00\x8b\x01\x00\x00\x87\x03\x01Ð\x118¿JÄ\x19[Òç\x01<O')
You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

Comment: May be overly simplistic, but I got this issue randomly when recovering my laptop from sleep and just restarting the computer solved the problem

Comment: after adding 
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
I had to do this trick to make it work:
- restart computer
- clear cache and cookies
- access http://127.0.0.1:800 then access http://127.0.0.1:8000 again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think you should create different settings.py ( base_settings.py, local_settings.py, production_settings.py). And in your settings.py do something like this:

```
import socket
if socket.gethostname()=="Raouf-PC":
    from local_settings import *
```

Change 'Raouf-PC' to the hostname of your PC.

P:S: I'm using Windows 10.

After doing that place the below data in your production_settings.py and save. Then clear your browser cache and visit your site in development server.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

If the above doesn't suit your needs, then in your local_settings.py paste the below data, save and clear your browser cache and visit your site.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
```

Note: at the beginning of production_setttings.py and local_settings.py put:

```
from base_settings.py import *
```

Your base settings should contain 'settings' that will be used both on local and production server so you won't be repeating it everytime.

P:S If my answer is accepted, I dedicate it to the good people on SO who have helped me in one way or the other. This is my first time of answering a question. I hope to do more in the future. :)

Comment: This prevents the problem. It does not solve it completely. Chrome and Firefox seem to remember settings for a certain page. Once this error occurs you can add these changes but you probably need to clear your browser caches as well.

Comment: It's not the best practice. Django app will expect that your computer is named as `Raouf-PC`. Other team members's laptops are named differently. Thus this condition won't work

Comment: Not working. Does this work in django 4.2?

Answer (score 23):

You probably have the setting [`SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#secure-ssl-redirect) set to `True`

This setting should be `False` when running the development server

Comment: This helped me access my site but I do want to access the site through https.

Comment: @JustinHarris to access your site over https you need to run the site through a server, NGINX + uWSGI or Apache + mod_python are two popular choices

Comment: Thanks Iain, actually I'm using pythonanywhere.com and it's pretty easy.

Comment: @SalahAdDin try clearing your cache. most browsers once they find out about the https version will keep trying to connect to that.

Answer (score 19):

Instead of using the command

`python manage.py runserver`

I used

`python manage.py runserver 8080`

Just by changing the port number, it is working for me.

Answer (score 8):

```
CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER      = False
HOST_SCHEME                     = "http://"
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER         = None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT             = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE           = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE              = False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS             = None
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  = False
SECURE_FRAME_DENY               = False
```

1. Put this settings at the end of your settings.py 
2. Clear your browser cache and then run your project.

Comment: Setting (only) `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` to `False` and clearing the browser cache worked for me.

Comment: @Mujeeb I tried this and it did not work for me... However, the settings above did make everything work fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you are part of a team, you can use a variable to set the development environment. I use `DJANGO_DEV=development`

for e.g., on the computer that will be used for development, you add this to your ~/.bashrc file:

`export DJANGO_DEV=true`

or you can use [django-environ](https://pypi.org/project/django-environ/)

After that you can check, if current environment is a DEV env and set the specific values.

```
import os

if os.environ.get('DJANGO_ENV') is not None:
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
else:
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

If there are multiple settings, that you can go and define specific files as described in @yoyo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the path in your `.env` file to http://localhost:8000/

It worked for me. I'm using the Django backend and React frontend with the Django rest framework.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing above helped me so digged in setting.py and
changed this to  `ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "https"`
this `ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "http"`
it fixed the problem for me hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to settings.py setup with `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False` for development.

To fix the https redirecting for localhost:

- Go to https://127.0.0.1:8000
- Open developer mode in your browser
- **Disable cache** on the Network tab
- Update the page with **http**://127.0.0.1:8000
- Enable cache

Or try **Empty Cache and Hard Reload** by right-clicking on the **update** icon in development mode in browser.

To open dev mode in Chrome use: Option + ⌘ + J (on macOS), or Shift + CTRL + J (on Windows/Linux)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old and already solved, but here it is for anyone who has a problem (as was my case today):

In my case, I followed (partially) as Huy Than proposed, after having changed SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT, CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE and SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE to **False**, I only **cleared the cache, restarted the IDE and the browser**.

I corrected the error and was able to access my website.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend to be sure that you are not trying access page by some port. For example by running Django server on PyCharm with some port.

Answer (score 0):

its clearly telling that you are accessing development server over https, but it only supports http.

usually we access development server like `http://127.0.0.1:8000` but in your case its `https://127.0.0.1:8000` as it's mentioned we cannot access development server over https.

I have gone through the same problem, but in my case when I was sending the email verification to gmail account, I was sending endpoint as `https://127.0.0.1:8000/verify`. https was used instead of http, so I corrected it to `http` then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert the below configs at the end of your settings.py file or completely comment them out(if you already had)

   SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = False
   SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = False
   SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
   SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
   CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
   X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'

then-,
2. Clear your browser cache and then re-run your project.

Answer (score 0):

### Check the Django's site URL. It may have https.

### Disable following variables in settings.py or .env

```
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['yoursite.com']
```

### Set DEBUG as True

```
DEBUG = True
```

### Clear the Django site's(what you developed) cookies and sessions on the browser. For Google Chrome, steps are below.

`Settings`-> `Privacy and Security` -> `Cookies and other site data` -> `See all cookies and site data` -> Search your site name or IP and click 'Trash' icon.

### Close the browser and reload the site now.

Answer (score 0):

The message: `You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.`.
It seems to be an error message unique for the Django environment.

My Firefox browser had remembered that I experimented in Django with redirecting http to https, so trafic to localhost was afterwards only with https, triggering the error message. Inside Firefox settings, I had to `Clear Data` for localhost. Now I can access localhost again with http.

In django `settings.py`, I solved the `http` to `https` redirect, like this:

```py
if IS_HEROKU_APP:
    # When running on web server
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
    SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
else:
    # When running on localhost
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the CORS error.
You must to add the 'corsheaders' in the Django setting.py installed apps

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     ...
     'corsheaders',
     'rest_framework'
]
```

add the middleware

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'coresheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    ......
]
```

and add the variable

```py
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```