# Repeatedly getting message: You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to Dockerize my Django application. In my settings.py I have all my security settings set to False if `DEBUG=True`. I specifically print both `f"DEBUG={DEBUG}"` and `f"SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = {SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT}"` at the bottom of my settings.py. But I am repeatedly getting the message `You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.`. What gives? I have seen [some other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536491/error-youre-accessing-the-development-server-over-https-but-it-only-supports/35536980) that indicate this variable is causing the problem, but that does not seem to be the case for me as it is most definitely set to False.

#### settings.py

```
# SITE SECURITY (security)
if DEBUG is False:
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
    SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
    SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 17068000 # > 6 months (197 days)
    SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
    SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
else:
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
    SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = False
    SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = False
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
    SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = False
    SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = False


print(f"SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = {SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT}")
```

#### docker-compose up output

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | December 08, 2019 - 21:32:49
web_1  | Django version 2.1.1, using settings 'my_app.settings'
web_1  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
web_1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
web_1  | "True"
web_1  | DEBUG=True
web_1  | SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  |
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | December 08, 2019 - 21:32:59
web_1  | Django version 2.1.1, using settings 'my_app.settings'
web_1  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
web_1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
web_1  | [08/Dec/2019 21:33:07] code 400, message Bad request syntax ("\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xfc\x03\x03\x1dn\xe4j\xdc8~\x02\xc2\x04\x89\xdd\x005^\xba\x9a\xa7\xa3xt\xc4.\xef,\xf7\x06\xedsOa\x81 \x87/E\xc9\xc1Hn\xe0%'\x93\xf4\t\xbd\xcb9")
web_1  | [08/Dec/2019 21:33:07] You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

Comment: Try to clear your browser's cache

Comment: Good advice, but unfortunately empty cache and hard reload does not fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: Wow. Firefox worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your server does not support https, so set these settings:

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=False
```

Or it may be a problem with your browser on chrome, Go to Settings > Privacy & Security > Clear Browsing History and set Time Range to all time and then clear your data. That worked for me.

Comment: Looks like these settings are already set in the `else` branch of settings.py in the question.